# Find command in windows 7

Tags: windows, eclipse, makefile

Recently migrated from windows XP to Windows 7.
I am using the eclipse environment for building the project. I have a make file with the below command

```
clean:
find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
```

This was used to search and delete the object files in the current directory.
After I moved to windows 7 the same command does not work. Below is the output of the command on Windows 7.

```
cs-make all 
find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
Access denied - .
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
File not found - -EXEC
File not found - RM
File not found - {}
File not found - ;
cs-make: *** [clean] Error 1***
```

My account has admin rights. Also I tried running eclipse using "run as admin". 
If someone knows the solution please let me know.

Comment: You cannot run UNIX shell commands like find(1) on Windows.  If it used to work on your Windows XP environment, then you must have installed some kind of UNIX tools package, such as cygwin or similar, on your Windows XP system and been using the version of make that comes with that.  Or perhaps you had installed a MinGW package and were using that.  You'll need to do the same thing in your Windows 7 system.

Comment: True. Sorry for not mentioning that. I have installed cygwin and also MinGW on the windows 7 but still i get the error. I checked the PATH in the eclipse environment, it does have the path to cygwin and path to MinGW.

Comment: Can you run that find command from your DOS terminal session?  I recommend you modify your system environment until you can open a terminal session and run that command without needing to set any paths, etc.  Then exit and restart Eclipse.  Heck, since it's Windows you might even try rebooting after you get the environment set.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks. Finally got it to work. It was the issue with the PATH. Added the proper path using command line , exit & restart eclipse did the trick. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi  @abdulrazak , did you try using the shell function of the makefile ??  like $(shell find-command)

Comment: I found that a simple addition to the path did not do the trick.  Indeed, the proper path specification for, in my case, `C:\cygwin64\bin`, was already present in the SYSTEM path.  To remedy the situation, I needed to move said cygwin path spec to be listed just BEFORE (again, in my case) `C:\windows` (also referred to as `%SystemRoot%`).  IHTH someone!

Comment: Sorry, there is an error in my above comment (mods, please delete).  The proper comment follows:  I found that a simple addition to the path did _not_ do the trick. Indeed, the proper path specification for, in my case, `C:\cygwin64\bin`, was already present in the SYSTEM path. To remedy the situation, I needed to move said cygwin path spec to be listed just AHEAD of (again, in my case) `C:\windows\system32` (also referred to as `%SystemRoot%\system32`). IHTH someone!