# (community detection algorithm) Infomap "make" throws error in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-module

I am trying to compile Infomap (community detection algorithm) to a python module as given in http://www.mapequation.org/code.html#Input but end up getting errors as below -

```
\examples\python>make
cd ../.. && make python
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - INTERFACES/SWIG
File not found - -NAME
make[1]: Entering directory `/d/PythonInstallables/Infomap/Third_Trial/mapequation-infomap-55e7e922c554/mapequation-infomap-55e7e922c554'
cp: missing destination file operand after `build/py/'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [py-build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/PythonInstallables/Infomap/Third_Trial/mapequation-infomap-55e7e922c554/mapequation-infomap-55e7e922c554'
make: *** [../../build/py/infomap.py] Error 2
```

Python version 2.7.7 (64-bit) on Windows 7.

Any clues regarding what might be wrong are welcome.
Also, i prefer to use Infomap seperately instead of through igraph as igraph does not provide advanced options as listed in the given Infomap link. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your errors:

```
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - INTERFACES/SWIG
File not found - -NAME
```

with the commands in the Makefile:

```
HEADERS := $(shell find src -name "*.h")
SOURCES := $(shell find src -name "*.cpp")
SWIG_FILES := $(shell find interfaces/swig -name "*.i”)
```

it seems that the problems are related to the find utility in Windows (see [Find command in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931023/find-command-in-windows-7)).

Probably you are using Windows without a properly installed Unix-like environment or tools. If that may be the case, try installing (or re-installing) MinGW or Cygwin. A simple way is to use the automated GUI installer assistant (see [MinGW - Getting Started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started)) and install the MSYS package from the MinGW installation manager. This gives you the required compiler and find tools.

---

## Update:

Even if the MSYS find utility is installed it has to be added to the PATH environment variable to be found. And MinGW doesn't do that by default (see link). Check the directories in the PATH by opening the command prompt and type

```
path
```

This will probably give you something like

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;…
```

The problem is that there is another find.exe located in the system32 folder, so for the Makefile to chose the correct find tool the directory containing the MSYS find utility has to be added *before* the system32 in the PATH.

Assuming the below location for MSYS you can do that by open a command prompt and type

```
set path=C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;%PATH%
```

This will set the directory of the MSYS find utility before all other directories to look up (expanded from the PATH environmental variable).

Note:

The above solution updates the path only for that session, so each time you open a new command prompt you have to type this in order to compile Infomap.

But adding it permanently first in the system wide PATH is not recommended as the MSYS utilities will shadow default Windows utilities with the same name, which may break other programs if they don't use absolute paths.

That is why the Getting Started guide writes

> We prefer that you use a script to set PATH for the processes on a per
>   session basis. This is the reason that we do not adjust the PATH.

You can simplify the procedure by doing this:

My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables

Here are two lists, the top one for user variables and the one below for system variables. Here you can check and edit the system wide PATH variable. But instead, create a new *user* variable and with the name and value like this:

```
Variable name: USE_MSYS
Variable value: set path=C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;%PATH%
```

Then when you need to use the MSYS utilities in the command prompt, just type

```
%USE_MSYS%
```

as a shortcut for the above.

MSYS also provide its own shell with the environmental variables already set up, but you have to configure it to find your files instead (see the link about fstab).

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!